# Eclipse RCP: New Editor Wizard

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, editor, eclipse-rcp, wizard

I have a small experience with Eclipse RCP - 3.X and I created my own editor via org.eclipse.ui.editors extension point and in order to have multiple instance of that editor I have implemented a new editor wizard as you can see below;

```java
IFile file = page1.createNewFile();

IWorkbenchWindow window = _workbench.getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
IWorkbenchPage page = window.getActivePage();
try {
    IDE.openEditor(page, file, SimpleEditor.ID, true);
} catch (PartInitException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

My question, the only way I found is that, create a new file and associate that file with your unique Editor ID. What I want is, I would like parse some initial values -that defined by user- to editor from the wizard. But we really don't instantiate the EditorPart class in the process.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: I would expect to have a New _File_ Wizard instead of a New _Editor_ Wizard that creates a file with the initial values and opens the file. The editor then reads the initial values from the file.

Comment: Are you saying you want to pass some parameters from the wizard to the editor?

Comment: Exactly! @greg-449

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `IDE.openEditor` call returns the `IEditorPart` that was opened - this will be an instance of your editor class so you can do:

```java
IEditorPart part = IDE.openEditor(page, file, SimpleEditor.ID, true);
if (part instanceof SimpleEditor) {
   SimpleEditor editor = (SimpleEditor)part;

   // TODO call methods you define in the editor to set the parameters
}
```

Alternatively you can use a custom `IEditorInput` and call the IDE

```java
openEditor(IWorkbenchPage page,
           IEditorInput input, String editorId)
```

method. The `init` method of the editor is given the `IEditorInput` you specify.

Comment: Hi I have one more question, how i can listen changes in Editor? @greg-449

Comment: Please don't ask new questions in comments - ask a new question so everyone can see it. In any case you need to provide more details as it is not clear what you are asking.